# Turning tags on and off?

Tags: google-tag-manager

I'm just getting started with GTM.  I'd like to use it primarily to send custom Analytics events about user actions.  However, I think I'm missing something obvious - is there a way to turn an event or a trigger on and off?  Like if I want to stop tracking some user action, but I might want to do it again later without having to delete/recreate everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no off setting for tags. Best workaround IMO is to create a trigger of the type "Custom Event", enable regular expressions and use ".*" as pattern for the event name. Then add this as trigger exception to the tag you want to pause. Since the exceptions fires on every event the tag will now never be fired. You still need to publish this, though, there is no quick on/off thing.